# docker file not found

Tags: java, maven, docker, docker-build

I am creating a docker image of a maven project.
Here is the docker file

```
FROM java:8
# Install maven
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y maven

WORKDIR ~/mmt/CouchBaseClient/CB-RestAPI/CacheService

# Prepare by downloading dependencies
#ADD pom.xml /mmt/CouchBaseClient/CB-RestAPI/CacheService/pom.xml
#RUN ["mvn", "dependency:resolve"]
#RUN ["mvn", "verify"]
ADD cacheService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /target/cacheService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 4567
CMD ["/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java", "-jar", "target/couchclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server cacheService.yml]
```

When I run the following command to build my image

```
 sudo docker build -t myimage .
```

I get the following error

```
 Step 5 : ADD cacheService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /target/cacheService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
 lstat cacheService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: no such file or directory
```

But I have my file there..How do i go about it

Comment: What seems to be missing to my answer?

Comment: Well it worked but the problem is when i change the path of file and give some random path still it is working. Its like its not searching the path its only searching the directory in which the docker file is

Comment: It should be searching the directory the Dockerfile is in and all its subfolders. Thatis the "context" of the docker build. Can you give an example of an ADD command (the full line, with the random path) where it still does work?

Comment: ADD cacheService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ~/mmt/CouchBaseClient/
Now i changed source to mmt/CouchBaseClient still it works

Comment: Do you mean `ADD mmt/CouchBaseClient/cacheService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ~/mmt/CouchBaseClient` "works" (when doing a `sudo docker build -t myimage .`) even though `./mmt/CouchBaseClient/cacheService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` does not exist on your host? (where the `Dockerfile` is)

Comment: Ok you are correct I was doing wrong

Comment: Great! Not sure what the downvote was for though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have `cacheService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` in the *same* folder as your `Dockerfile`.

That way, it will be part of your [docker build context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) when you do a `sudo docker build -t myimage .`

The "source" (in "`ADD <source> <destination>`") is a relative path to the PATH used in `docker build` (here '`.`': current directory).